# Set column widths of one sheet the same as another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write code that sets the column widths in one sheet to be the same as the column widths in another sheet. It didn't go as straightforward as I thought it would, so I'm posting it here in an attempt to determine if it can be accomplished in an easier manner.

It seems that when I read the width of the column in one sheet, in order to set the width of the column in the other sheet I have to add a correction factor to get the right width. The correction factor is (ReadWidth / 0.75 - 5) / 7.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
Function SetWidths()
Dim Cntr As Integer, Column As String, Sht1 As String, Sht2 As String
Dim Sht1Wid As Double, Sht2Wid As Double, Sht1WidSet As Double, Sht2WidSet As Double

Sht1 = "Sheet1"
Sht2 = "Sheet2"

For Cntr = 1 To 55

    Column = Num2Col(Cntr)

    Sht1Wid = Worksheets(Sht1).Range(Column & "1").Width                ' read width
    Sht2Wid = Worksheets(Sht2).Range(Column & "1").Width
    Sht1WidSet = (Sht1Wid / 0.75 - 5) / 7                               ' correction factor
    Sht2WidSet = (Sht2Wid / 0.75 - 5) / 7

    If Sht1Wid <> Sht2Wid Then
        If Sht1Wid > Sht2Wid Then                                       ' set width to largest
            Worksheets(Sht2).Columns(Column).ColumnWidth = Sht1WidSet
        Else
            Worksheets(Sht1).Columns(Column).ColumnWidth = Sht2WidSet
        End If
    End If

Next Cntr

End Function
```

Num2Col is another function that returns a string for the column based upon the number.

Does anyone have an easier way to do this? It seems odd that the correction factor has to be added.

Comment: There should be no need for a "correction factor". Check which cell styles apply to both the sheets. The column widths are not absolute numbers (like pixels etc), but are based on the size of the font of the "Normal" cell style. If you have changed the styles on one of the sheets but not the other, that would account for the change in size.

Comment: If I change the references to use the .ColumnWidth property instead of the .Width property I get the right values. I'm not sure what the .Width property returns, but it seems to be proportional to the column width with the calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would:
- Copy an entire row of Sheet1
- Paste Special, column widths onto the other sheets:

```
Sub AdjustColumns()
    Dim oSh As Worksheet
    Worksheets(1).Range("1:1").Copy
    For Each oSh In Worksheets
        If oSh.Index > 1 Then
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had ot be a simpler way. Don't even need vba, can just use copy and paste special - column widths. I should have looked there first.

Comment: Yes and if you group the sheets, only one paste is needed.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer @BlairH . Also, I'd clear the clipboard to avoid memory leak or confusions due to so many data being pasted there,   by changing this line should be enough .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths:Application.CutCopyMode = False